# How do I merge two data frames using either concat or merge?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge the two data frames that look like this: 
https://i.imgur.com/ZCPzx7V.png

What would I write to merge the two?

I've been through this but I am still getting errors:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/joining-dataframes-pandas

Comment: show us the code for which you got the error?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this ( assuming that the first dataframe is `df1` and the second one `df2` ) -

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='letter', right_on='alpha')
```

Comment: So, it turns out I was doing it correctly. The problem was spaces in my CSV file. I had copied and pasted information from a PDF to a CSV and all of the cells had trailing spaces. I had to use TRIM() in Excel to remove them. Then the code worked. 

When you do this on the job, do you clean up the CSV in Excel or do you  make all changes like removing spaces in Pandas?

Comment: Either should be fine. However, if you do it in `pandas`, you would be able to remove an intermediate tool. Check out the `strip()` function in pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html

Comment: I meant in terms of best practices for a job. For example, is it right to edit the data source file or should it be left alone and all cleaning done in Pandas?

Comment: I think it is better not to edit the data source file and do cleaning on a copy of it. You could always refer back to the source file in case you want to check for an error, which may have got introduced.

Answer (score 0):

To merge 2 dataframes, we need to have a column based on which the 2 dataframes can be combined.

`df1 : letter | a_count` and `df2 : alpha | name`
These dataframes are combined based on the columns `letter` and `alpha` in `df1` and `df2` respectively.

For this, first we rename the column `alpha` as `letter` in df2 and then merge these 2 dataframes based on their common column `letter`

```py
df2 = df2.rename(columns = {'alpha': 'letter'})
pd.merge(df1,df2, on='letter')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.